# Cartesian Point Shifting Period

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Say **(x, y)** is a point made of nonnegative integers. **p** and **q** are two prime numbers and **n** is another positive integer, with p, q, and n fixed throughout this problem. The point is shifted z number of times (with z a varying dummy variable) using the following rules. (% is the binary modulo operator.)

$$x_{new} = (x_{old} + p)\ \%\ (n - 1)$$
$$y_{new} = (y_{old} + q)\ \%\ n$$

Is the sequence of resulting positions periodic? If yes, what is the period?

---

For example, Let the initial value (x, y) = (1, 1) and p = 2, q = 3, n = 7, then,
x = (x + 2) % 6
y = (y + 3) % 7
Take z = 4 and the successive postions are calculated as

**1. z = 1**
x = (1 + 2) % 6 = 3
y = (1 + 3) % 7 = 4
so, (x, y) = (3, 4)

**2. z = 2**
x = (3 + 2) % 6 = 5
y = (4 + 3) % 7 = 0
so, (x, y) = (5, 0)

**3. z = 3**
x = (5 + 2) % 6 = 1
y = (0 + 3) % 7 = 3
so, (x, y) = (1, 3)

**4. z = 4**
x = (1 + 2) % 6 = 3
y = (3 + 3) % 7 = 6
so, (x, y) = (3, 6)

Comment: $z$ is not used in your formulas but $n$ is. Are they the same? If not, what is the meaning of $n$?

Comment: z is number of iterations, n is a constant.

Comment: Do you know anything about $n$ or $n-1$, such as is it prime, its greatest common divisor with $p$ and $q$, and so on? And are you asking if the shifts themselves are periodic, or the positions after the accumulated shifts?

Comment: n and n - 1 are just constant nothing specific as prime, gcd or anything else.

Comment: I am talking about positions after accumulated shifts

Comment: @MathsFun It doesn't solve the problem, does it?

Comment: @Awesome Yes it solves, the formula gives the period.

Comment: @MathsFun We both know that isn't what I am asking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for $x$, it cycles through the values $0,1,\ldots,n-2$ "as much as possible." If $p$ and $n-1$ have a greatest common divisor that is greater than $1$, all the resulting values of $x$ will have the same remainder when divided by that gcd. Therefore, $x$ will cycle through a certain pattern, and the number of possible values of $x$ is

$$\frac{n-1}{\operatorname{gcd}(n-1,p)}$$

$y$ is similar, but it cycles through $0,1,\ldots,n-1$ and is limited by the greatest common divisor of $q$ and $n$. So, $y$ will cycle through a certain pattern, and the number of possible values of $y$ is

$$\frac{n}{\operatorname{gcd}(n,q)}$$

The joint pattern of $(x,y)$ will cycle, with the number of values being the least common multiple of their individual cycles. So, your point $(x,y)$ is indeed periodic, with period

$$\operatorname{lcm}\left(\frac{n-1}{\operatorname{gcd}(n-1,p)},\frac{n}{\operatorname{gcd}(n,q)}\right)$$

Note that the period does not depend on the starting values of $x$ and $y$. Note also that the prime-hood of $p$ and $q$ is irrelevant, just their greatest common divisors with $n-1$ and $n$ respectively, though their being prime does make finding the gcd's quick and easy.

In your particular example, with $p = 2,\ q = 3,\ n = 7$, the period is

$$\operatorname{lcm}\left(\frac{7-1}{\operatorname{gcd}(7-1,2)},\frac{7}{\operatorname{gcd}(7,3)}\right)=
\operatorname{lcm}\left(\frac{6}{2},\frac{7}{1}\right)=21$$

I made a quick test of this in Microsoft Excel, and it checks.